# Hyper-V Fails to enable replication between servers with error 0x00002EE2

Tags: hyper-v

I am running into an issue trying to enable hyper-v replication on Windows Server 2016.  I have tried via HTTP and HTTPS (AD signed certificates) and neither works.  The interesting thing is, I already have another VM replicating between the two servers so I know its possible.

The current error is:

```
[Main Instruction]
Enabling replication failed.

[Expanded Information]
Hyper-V failed to enable replication for virtual machine 'VM2': The operation timed out (0x00002EE2). (Virtual machine ID 134E9F3F-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1AC608804212)
```

However this doesn't make sense as I can ping the server (ping works from both sides) and I can connect to port 80 and 443 from each side (VS1 and VS2) - note they are on different subnets however that shouldn't matter. Also both servers are part of the domain so authentication shouldn't be an issue (I am logged in as a domain admin and have a valid kerberos ticket) and there is nothing in any of the event logs that gives me any sort of clue as to what is wrong.

Anyone have any ideas of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

just had the same problem. This link helped me a lot:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24258.hyper-v-troubleshooting-error-0x00002ee2-while-enabling-replication.aspx

as described it could be a problem with your routing. I was able to solve it by enabling BypassProxyServer

the powershell command should look something like this (Keep in mind that this configuration is powershell only):

```
Set-VMReplication -vmname "name" -AuthenticationType Kerberos -ReplicaServerName "servername" -ReplicaServerPort "Port" -BypassProxyServer $true
```

Comment: Got same problem and this command fixed it. Cheers and thanks.